# Using number provided in submit as variable?

Tags: javascript

I need help understanding how to fix this.

```
<p> Enter a number in the box. </p>

<div> 
    <label for ="numberSubmitted"> Number: </label> 
    <input type="text"   class="numberSubmitted">      
    <input type = "submit"  value="Submit">
</div>

 <div>
    <p class="message"></p>
</div>

var numberSubmitted = Number(numberSubmitted.value);
var message = document.querySelector(".message");

if(numberSubmitted > 100) {
 message.textContent = "You won!";
}  else {
 message.textContent = "You lose!";
}
```

What's happening is that "You Lose!" is being printed out if I leave the variable as

```
var numberSubmitted = Number()
```

If change it to

```
var numberSubmitted = Number(numberSubmitted.value)
```

the code just doesn't work.

I don't see online any guide to tell you how to use Number() with classes.
Can anyone please point me in right direction on when to include class when defining the Number method?

Comment: Use F12 developer tools (in particular, the console) and you should see the problem.  If it's not clear to you, then console.log(numberSubmitted.value) and check F12 console.

Comment: P.S.  another hint:  JavaScript needs to be inside script tags.  That isn't your entire problem, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things:

1. The "for" in label needs to point to an id, not a class.
2. Your problem with it not working when you try to put numberSubmitted.value into Number() is that numberSubmitted is undefined, to fix this you need to get the html element of your input box and do .value on that.
3. You need to put your JavaScript in a script tag.

Try the following:

```
<p> Enter a number in the box. </p>

<div>
    <label for="numberSubmitted"> Number: </label>
    <input type="text" id="numberSubmitted">
    <input type = "submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
</div>

<div>
    <p class="message"></p>
</div>

<script>
function submit() {
    var numberSubmitted = Number(document.getElementById('numberSubmitted').value);
    var message = document.querySelector(".message");

    if(numberSubmitted > 100) {
     message.textContent = "You won!";
    }  else {
     message.textContent = "You lose!";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using an event listener instead of the inline function call:

[JS Fiddle Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/kpqoaknm/).

**HTML**

```
<p> Enter a number in the box. </p>

<div>
  <label for="numberSubmitted"> Number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="numberSubmitted">
  <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Submit">
</div>

<div>
  <p class="message"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//bind the listener to the button
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
//get the input element
var el = document.getElementById('numberSubmitted');

function myFunction() {
  var numberSubmitted = Number(el.value);
  //for debug
  console.log(numberSubmitted);
  var message = document.querySelector(".message");
  if (isNaN(numberSubmitted)) {
    message.textContent = "That isn't a number.";
    return;
  }
  if (numberSubmitted > 100) {
    message.textContent = "You won!";
  } else {
    message.textContent = "You lose!";
  }
}
```

As mentioned in my comments earlier, you need to wrap your JS in script tags.  I've made other comments in the code segments above.  You'll notice that wrapping your original JS in script tags isn't enough -- there is still an 'undefined' error pertaining to the numberSubmitted element.  This is because JS has no idea what `numberSubmitted` is -- you need to find the element in the DOM and assign it to a variable.  I've shown you how to do that above.

Comment: I have the script tags, but I took them out to save space, but I understand.